# cant get_cli install in flutter: Warning: Executable "get" runs "bin\get.dart", which was not found in get_cli

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, get-cli

I want to install getx_cli but when I running the command below, error is found

```
flutter pub global activate get_cli
```

error:

```
Package get_cli is currently active at version 1.7.1.
Resolving dependencies...
The package get_cli is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `flutter pub global deactivate get_cli`.
Installed executables get and getx.
Warning: Executable "get" runs "bin\get.dart", which was not found in get_cli.
Warning: Executable "getx" runs "bin\get.dart", which was not found in get_cli.
Activated get_cli 1.7.1.
```

I have added PATH: [FlutterSDKInstallDir]\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin to my system enviroments variables.

Used flutter version is Flutter version 2.10.3 and installed get_cli packet version is 1.7.1

Answer (score 2):

Try this *command*

```
dart pub global activate get_cli
```